# how can I get properties of a model with for loop

Tags: c#

Is there a way to cycle through all the fields/properties of any given model and get both the name and the type?  What is the "type" for a model?  Every Controller inherits from Controller what do models inherit from?  I know it is simply a class - how do you pass a type of class to a method?

Comment: Unless they explicitly inherit from a type they will inherit from `object`.  There is no "base" type for models in general.

Comment: Sounds like you want to read up on the topic of `Reflection`.

Comment: @DStanley if I try to pass a model as an object to a method it does not contain properties or at least I don't know how to get them.

Comment: You have 4 questions, at least one of which is a duplicate.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt - how do I use reflection to do what I want?

Comment: @Dean.DePue Read the duplicate I marked.  It should show you _exactly_ how to loop through properties without knowing the type.  `GetType`, `GetProperties`, and `GetValue` are "reflection" methods.

Comment: AFAIK, in ASP.NET MVC, your models do not need to inherit from any specific class. You may leave it without any base class (in this case, the base class is object), or you may inherit form any class you want.